# Exposing headers with C++ classes to other packages

Tags: r, rcpp

I am writing custom functionality for an R package. My classes inherit from the classes in the package, i.e.

package `orig` has `src/myclass.h` with class

```
class myClass {
public:
    virtual int blub(int bla) { return(bla + 1); }
}
```

I want my package `derivedpackage` to use

```
#include "orig/myclass.h"
class derivClass : public myClass { ... }
```

I am aware that I need in my `DESCRIPTION`:

```
LinkingTo: orig
```

And somewhere I guess `[[Rcpp:depends(orig)]]` in the `src/derivClass.h` or so.

And I am aware that the original package `orig` will need headers in `inst/include`.

**Questions:**

- **what else do I need to add to `orig`?**
- **is there an automated way via Rcpp attributes to get my headers into `inst/include`?** I know `[[Rcpp::interfaces(R, cpp)]]` exists but it doesn't seem to apply to exporting classes, only functions; putting `[[Rcpp::export]]` in front of the class doesn't seem to be doing anything.

For simplicity let's assume that I maintain both packages but just don't want to have the `derivedpackage` functionality in `orig` because it is more specific and only useful for a special case.

Comment: I recommend you check how the package ‹BH› does it: that should give you all you need to know (minus, potentially, how to do it automatically).

Comment: Yes and no; BH is a pure header package and so everything can just go into /inst/include; there is no /src at all...

Comment: The source part is discussed at some length in Writing R Extensions; you would have to explicitly register eacg method ... which is tedious.  See several packages that do that for C interfaces.  Also, in fairness to @KonradRudolph your question did not mention `src/` AFAICT ...